# Change image when mouse hovers on buttons

Tags: excel, image, vba, mousehover

I just wanna ask. What will be the code if the mouse will hover on the buttons and then suddenly the image in the userform will instantly change.

Btw this is Excel VBA.

Please see below the image.

[[image: enter image description here[1]]

Thank you and regards,

Answer (score 0):

you should implement the mouseMove event of your Button.

```
Private Sub YourButtonName_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
  'your Code Here 

End Sub
```

But watch out this is called each time you move the mouse on the button. So You should check whenever you draw the image or not.

Comment: Hi Basslo, Thank you i did add image1.picture = loadpicture (picpath)